# Netbeans 8.0 scene builder Adding Error

Tags: netbeans-8, scenebuilder

When I go to Options>Java>JavaFX and set Scene Builder path to the Applications folder, I get the error:
Selected location does not represent a valid JavaFX Scene Builder installation

Answer (score 1):

It works fine with the NetBeans 8.2 and further , try to install the latest version